# why bufferreader returns null on readLine()

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a `BufferReader` from `InputStreamReader` which loads response from webservice like this:

```
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
try {
    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    // returns null
    String line = reader.readLine();

    // correctly instantiates Article object
    Article article = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Article.class);
```

However, for some reason, `reader.readLine();` returns `null`, although the data successfully came from the server - I know that because Article object is correctly instantiated from the returned JSON. What could be the reason for returning `null`?

Comment: Because it reached the end of the stream.

Comment: But how is this possible if it's the first `readLine` statement? Does it mean that nothing came from server?

Comment: Yes, it's one possibility.

Comment: But then this `Article article = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Article.class); ` should not have `Article` object correctly instantiated, right?

Comment: how did you define your Url url?

Answer (score 2):

Hm, that's odd... It worked perfectally fine for me when I did this:

```
File file = new File("plugin.yml");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

reader.close();
```

I know, you have stated that you have tested everything with the System.out.println(stuff), but I'll still ask the most basic questions and maybe the problem is hidden somewhere in there:
Does it even enter the method?
Is the file correctly spelled (also from where you add log to the log)?
Does it work, if you use the Scanner to read the file?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
String line;

while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    line = scan.nextLine();
    //...
}

scan.close();
```

These are probably all silly questions, but it might help. As for now, I can't see any problems in your code.

Comment: thanks, but you're reading from a file, I'm reading from webservice

Comment: @Maximus exactly.. this is an indication that something wrong with the server's response.

Comment: You can just try to use the scanner and implement your logic. That did the trick for me. Give it a Try.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you missed to set the connection output to true.
Furthermore I'd do it something like this:

```
try {
  URL url = new URL("http://im-an-url.com");
  HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  c.setDoOutput(true);
  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream());
  //do whatever you like here with the StreamWriter
  wr.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
try {
c.connect();
if (c.getResponseCode == 200) {


InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

// returns null
String line = reader.readLine();

// correctly instantiates Article object
Article article = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Article.class); 
 }
```

make sure the net stream has end tag \r\n if you use readLine method, or you can use BufferOutputStream

Comment: thanks, `c.connect(); if (c.getResponseCode() == 200) {                            Log.d("TEST", "established");` outputted `established`. Can you clarify this please _make sure the net stream has end tag \r\n if you use readLine method, or you can use BufferOutputStream_?